# Python number list summarisation by range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of numbers and I'd like to print a list which summarise them into ranges. For example

Input

`number_list = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11]`

Output

`['1 to 3',5,7,'9 to 11']`

My approach -

```
temp_list = []
final_list = []
number_list = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11]

for i in range(len(number_list)):
   if number_list[i-1] not in temp_list or i == 0:
      temp_list.append(number_list[i])
   else:
      if number_list[i] - number_list[previous_i] != 1:
         temp_list.append(previous_item)
         if temp_list[0] != temp_list[1]:
            final_list.append(f'{temp_list[0]} to {temp_list[1]}')
         else:
            final_list.append(temp_list[0])
         temp_list = []
      else:
         final_list.append(number_list[i])
   previous_item = number_list[i]
   previous_i = i

print (final_list)
# O/P : [2, '1 to 3', 7, 11] which should be ['1 to 3',5,7,'9 to 11']
```

But I am still not getting my desired output. Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [more_itertools.consecutive_groups](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups):

```
import more_itertools as mit

groups = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(number_list)]

[f'{g[0]} to {g[-1]}' if len(g) > 1 else g[0] for g in groups]
```

outout:

```
['1 to 3', 5, 7, '9 to 11']
```

Comment: Thanks ! However 9 seems to appear twice !

Comment: @TanishqChaudhary check now my answer